# Does defining a tuneGrid in R's caret automatically trigger a GridSearch?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, hyperparameters

I am working on a multi-class classification project, currently at the stage of hyperparameter optimization.  Running a grid search was fine, using R and caret, defining a grid and passing it to the `trainGrid` parameter within `train`. It took about 1.5 days to run, but not unsurprising given the hardware I am using and the size of the grid.

Now I am experimenting with other options, specifically Random Search, currently my code looks like this:

```
paramGrid <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800),
  max_depth = c(4, 6, 8, 10),
  eta = seq(0.05, 0.25, length.out = 5),
  gamma = seq(0, 0.1, length.out = 3),
  colsample_bytree = seq(0.6, 1, length.out = 3),
  min_child_weight = c(1, 3, 5),
  subsample = seq(0.6, 1, length.out = 3)
)

trainControlMethod <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,  
  repeats = 1,
  search = "random",
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  allowParallel = TRUE 
)

randomSearchModel <- train(
  x = X,  
  y = y,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = trainControlMethod,
  #tuneGrid = paramGrid,
  tuneLength = 60,  
  metric = "Accuracy"
)
```

The intent with the above code is to try 60 tuning parameters (Randomly), using 10-fold stratified CV.

If I leave the `tuneGrid` line commented, it behaves as I would expect RandomSearch to behave.  If I uncomment `tuneGrid`, it suddenly goes from 1-2.5 hours to 2.5 days of running, which makes me think that it triggers a Grid Search despite `search = "random"` is defined.

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-92/topics/train), `tuneGrid` is

> a data frame with possible tuning values. The columns are named the same as the tuning parameters

but says nothing about converting the behaviour to a Grid Search.

All tutorials I've found don't define any Grid for the Random Search to operate on, so if there's no Grid, how does Random Search know the upper and lower limits of the parameters to try?

Does defining `tuneGrid` within the `train` function in R's caret, automatically trigger a Grid Search (despite Random Search being defined)?

Comment: There does not seem to be any `search` argument in `trainControl` docs: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/trainControl

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-92/topics/trainControl `search` "Either "grid" or "random", describing how the tuning parameter grid is determined"

Comment: You're right, it is there in the newest versions; updated your doc link to point to the newest version 6.0 (instead of the 4.x one).

Comment: Please edit your post to include exactly the `expand.grid` values you have used; the issue may have more to do with `tuneLength`, which seems to be functional only when the search gird has *not* been defined explicitly.

Comment: My 2 cents (no time to dig further): I *suspect* that `tuneLength` is not taken into account when `tuneGrid` has been explicitly defined (the documentation is not terribly clear on this), so the actual difference is between running only 60 trials versus 12,960 (the number of combinations of your actual grid).